# Update data in DB2 database table using python pandas

Tags: python, pandas, db2

I am looking for a code which can update data in few columns in DB2 database using Python pandas.

I tried this code by updating data into 4th, 6th & 8th Column. But gives an error and the values are not updated:

> IndexError: index out of bounds

```
df = df[['Col1','Col2','Col3']]

sql_update = "UPDATE DATABASE.SCHEMA SET COLUMN_3=?,COLUMN_5=?,COLUMN_7=?)"

stmt1 = ibm_db.prepare(con, sql_update)

for index,item in df.iterrows():
        ibm_db.execute(stmt1, (item[3],item[5],item[7]))
```

Is there a better way to update data into DB2 database using pandas?

Answer (score 0):

When you do `iterrows()`, the output is index & the content.
So, you will have to find the index you want to use & then call the content of that index.
Example below

```
for idx,item in df.iterrows():
    if (idx == 3)|(idx == 5)|(idx == 7):
        ibm_db.execute(stmt1,item)
```

Check if this works for you.

Comment: No it dint. this is the error: Exception: "Param is not a tuple"

Comment: I think we must execute it as tuple. Something like this. 
tuple_of_tuples = tuple([tuple(x) for x in df.values])